# Is there any way to write comments with AngularJS so that they are not visible when viewing the source

Tags: javascript, comments, angularjs

When writing JSPs, I always use `<%-- --%>` instead of `<!-- -->` to write any comments, since it will not output to the HTML. I have begun using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), and I'm wondering if there's any similar kind of comment construct that I could use. It's not absolutely necessary to not have the comments visible in the HTML source, but I much rather them not being there.

With the limited knowledge I have of AngularJS, I'm not sure how they could prevent it from being in the source, but I just want to ask in case there is a way. Perhaps there's also a best practice for comments in AngularJS? Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

AngularJS is a library for dynamic features in HTML/JS/CSS pages. It's not a template language such as JavaServer Pages. As such, it doesn't have a special syntax for comments. You can still use HTML style comments of course.

Comment: Makes sense. I just wanted to throw it out there in case there was some part I didn't understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a pre-deployment processing tool such as grunt uglify. It will allow you to strip out comments and do more useful deployment pre-processing such as minifying code.

[grunt uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify)

Answer (score 1):

Use directives:

```
myApp.directive('comment', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs){
            $(element).remove();
        }
    };
}]);
```

example:

```
<comment>Remove me</comment>
```

Comment: This would remove it from the DOM, but it would still be in the page source.

Comment: and where to write these directives?